# Mnemonics for learning the days of the week

Tags: learning, mnemonic, time

I can't memorize and repeat quickly the days of the week even though I studied English for several years (I always need to count with my fingers).
How are the name of the days taught to children? Is there a song, a doggerel or something else?

Comment: It might help if you associate their names to planets they are named after. The most obvious ones are Sunday and Monday, from the Sun and the Moon. Saturday is from Saturn. Thursday is named after Thor (Yes, the god in those superhero movies!) Here is the complete list: Sunday (Sun), Monday (Moon), Tuesday (Mars), Wednesday (Mercury), Thursday (Jupiter), Friday (Venus), Saturday (Saturn).

Comment: @DamkerngT. Sunday, Monday, and Saturday are named after the Sun, Moon, and Saturn (the god, not the planet), but Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday are all named after Norse gods (Tiu, Wodin, Thor, and Freya.)

Comment: I used the song in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CB79gFbAh0k) to teach my children the names of the days of the week.  There are puppets...

Comment: Not clear to me how knowing the names of the gods and planets the days are named after helps to remember them. Do you really say, "Day after Tuesday ... uh, umm ... oh yes! Woden follows Tiu!" But if it works for you, cool.

Comment: @Jay No, not at all, but Damkerng T. suggested that the days corresponded to planets, which I found confusing.  I figured Alessio might as well.  (To be fair there is a decent correspondence between the roles of the Norse gods and the planets named after the Roman gods.)

Comment: @JasonPatterson The names of those Norse gods are useful! Because they sound quite close to English days of week. (Tiu's day, Wodin's day, Thor's day, Freya day) I suggested the planets because in my first language, days of week can be mapped to those planets, and exactly in that order. I just hoped that the OP's first language might have something similar, too.

Comment: http://www.rhymes.org.uk/mondays_child.htm

Comment: @DamkerngT.: The Roman gods (and of course their namesake planets!) are certainly behind the weekdays in several languages (in French, Mars, Mercury, Jove (Jupiter) and Venus are more recognizable), but the _order_ seems arbitrary (the planets are not in the order of the weekdays in any sense) so I doubt that order helps much :)

Comment: @oerkelens Exactly! And yet a lot of languages, not only Indo-European ones, end up using exactly that seemingly arbitrary order. I'm sure that if I really wanted to know the reason why, I could look into etymology or astrology to get some satisfying answers. :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think the names of the days (at least their etymologies) may have predated (at least in part) the discovery of the planets - or at least their actual classification as planets. I think the days and the planets where both named after the gods, not the days after the planets or vice versa. As for non-Indo-European languages that use Roman gods fro the weekdays, I figure they may simply have borrowed the names (and sometimes the whole calendar).

Comment: The best way to really learn these is to use them every day.  Don't just think of them as a list to memorize, *use* them!  Do everything with an English calendar, say the full date to yourself including the day of the week every day, and so on.  If you're planning on doing something tomorrow, say to yourself "It's *Tuesday* now, so tomorrow, on *Wednesday*, I'll take the garbage out and water the lawn."

Comment: It's easy to confuse Tuesday with Thursday.

Answer (score 3):

Community wiki answer to compile the suggestions.

#### Songs

[The Days of the Week](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CB79gFbAh0k) - *MapleLeafHashima*
[Days of the Week (Adams Family)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIvQOab00OQ) - *Michelle Lebowe*
[Seven Days of the Week (I Never Go to Work)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geTSBFb_GR4) - *They Might Be Giants*
[Happy Days Theme Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VijD3WjREgw) - *Charles Fox (score) and Norman Gimbel (lyrics)*

#### Rhymes

[Monday's Child Poem](http://www.rhymes.org.uk/mondays_child.htm) - *Nursery Rhyme*

#### Techniques

Get 7 index cards. On each index card, write down one day of the week. If possible, write a sentence that uses the day of the week in a specific context, preferably one personally meaningful to you. Ex: On Sundays people go to church. Monday is the first day of the work week. Tuesday is when I watch -- on TV. Wednesday is hump day (the middle day of the work week). Friday is the last day of the work week. Saturday I watch football on TV. Practice the index cards.

Read English-language news, as days of the week are commonly encountered there.

Physical action can sometimes help you remember. My husband learned some Polish words because his Physical Education teacher (who was Polish) would count out the student's push-ups and other exercises using Polish numbers, week day names, month names, etc. and he remembered them quite well.

If you take a vitamin every day, a [weekly pill box](http://amzn.com/B0000537JP) might help you remember the days.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question... Children are taught the days of the week by exposure, not songs or mnemonics. There may be repetition, much as I learned how to count to 20 in Spanish or all of my names (I have three middle names), but it's mostly just repetition.

I know this is less-helpful than the other suggestions made, but I hope it explains why there aren't any really catchy jingles to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this mnemonic will help: "**My Turtle Won't Take French Studies Seriously**".

It gives you a basic scaffolding to remember and helps to choose between **Tu**esday (**Tu**rtle) and Thursday, between **S**a**tu**rday (**Stu**dies) and Sunday.