# Is there an easy way to learn the month names in English?

Tags: memorization

I can't memorize and repeat quickly **the month names** in English even though I've been studying English. I'd like to know if there are some ways or maybe a strategy **to learn the month names** in English.

Comment: There is a question about learning the day names that has some techniques that might be helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/38392

Comment: @ِDear ColleenV, I don't have problem with the day names, but unfortunately I have trouble with  the month names

Comment: What is your native language? Do you know any other languages with comparable month names (French, German, Russian, Dutch)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about memory aids, not English as such.

Comment: Is it necessary to say  the names of the months rapidly?  If you have difficulties I wouldn't learn those names. Each month you see the name a lot of times. And I would not try 12 names, try groups of three names. And I think there are more important things than rattling down the twellve names.

Comment: Many of the same techniques used to remember day names can be used to remember month names. How did you learn the month names in your native language? There's nothing special about English month names - there are twelve of them, just like there are in most other languages, and they are single words. It's just a vocabulary problem.

Comment: Learning English (and any language) includes "memory aids."

Answer (score 2):

I memorized the month names like this:

"January, February,
March, April, May,
June, July, August,
September, October, November, December".

Here are some mnemonics that can help:

- January [is named](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=January) for the two-faced Roman god Janus, who looked both backwards and forwards.
- February [might be named for a time of burnt offerings](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=February) at the end of the old Roman calendar.
- Then there are six short names in a row:

  - March was the first month of the old Roman calendar; March 25 used to be the first day of the English calendar.  It is named for the Roman god Mars.
  - April, May, and June are girls' names.  "April showers bring May flowers."
  - July is named for the first Roman emperor, Julius Cæsar.
  - August is named for the second Roman Emperor, Augustus.
- September, October, November, and December count the months (starting with March!):
  "sept-" = 7, "oct-" = 8, "nov-" = 9, "dec-" = 10.

Comment: Does this help? Because I can't see how....

Comment: It's entertaining. And sometimes that helps :-)

Comment: The "starting with march" bit is incorrect. The reason that the months 9 to 12 are called 7 to 10 in latin is that the roman emperors Julius and Augustus wanted months named after themselves, but they wanted summer months... so they put their months in the middle and moved the later months on by two.

Comment: That's not correct.  The emperors renamed two existing months, Quintilis and Sextilis, after themselves.  The old 10 month Roman calendar began with March.  January and February were added around 700BC.